# Java Generics Typecasting

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a question regarding Java Generics. Suppose I have the following method:

```
public <U> Logger<U> flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Logger<? extends U>> fMapper) {
      
      LoggerImpl<? extends U> updatedLogger = (LoggerImpl<? extends U>) fMapper.apply(this.item);
      ...
```

How do I interpret the above typecast with the wildcards <? extends U>? And what is the difference between using that compared to just `LoggerImpl<U> updatedLogger = (LoggerImpl<U>) fMapper.apply(this.item);`?

Comment: It means you can also use a super class of `U`.  Without more context I can't say why that is necessary or a good idea.

Comment: You mean a subclass @markspace

Comment: Right, sorry, it's `T` that can take a super class.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what `LoggerImpl<? extends U>`  is saying is that it can be either U or any subclass of U, if you have `LoggerImpl<U> updatedLogger` you have to use U and subclasses would not work.

Hope I helped!